# How to define PasswordBox type column in DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit, passwordbox

How to make a column in WPFToolkit:DataGrid PasswordBox like?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Made it through DataGridTemplateColumn

Example:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Password">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <PasswordBox />
          </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Now I have another problem. I am trying to bind column to CLR object. but VS says: 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Password' property of type 'PasswordBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: PasswordBox.Password doesn't have a corresponding DependencyProperty, so you can't data-bind to it.

Exposing a DependencyProperty would require us to store the PasswordBox content plain text in memory in the property system -- which is a security concern.  The PasswordBox encrypts its content and only generates plain text on demand when a caller references the Password CLR property.

via: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7ca97b60-2d8e-4a27-8c5b-b8d5d7370a5e/

Comment: This answer is not useful to others. Please post a working answer with an explanation.

Comment: @Stealth Rabbi sorry, I can't. my days of working with .Net and WPF are long gone. Check the dates.

Comment: Yes, it was answered 6 years ago. If only it was answered with an actual solution...

Answer (score 1):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Password">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <PasswordBox Name="PasswordBoxPass"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: anyone else have this problem? - Password box in a datagrid goes blank when you tab out of it? Seems to only happen when you tab into it. Double clicking in the password box seems to hold the display value after tabbing out. Also seems that you have to tab twice into it. First tab seems to focus the cell rather than the control. I only mention this here because it seems this example is the correct way to do it but no one seems to be talking about the bugs.